# Base API Controller with Generics

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to implement a simple Base class for my Web API 2 controllers - they should always have a Entity Framework repo and a `Dispose` method -

```
public abstract class BaseController<TRepo> : ApiController where TRepo : Repository<EF.DBContext>, new()
{
    private readonly TRepo _repo;

    protected TRepo Repo { get { return _repo; } }


    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _repo.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

The inheriting contoller -

```
public class EntriesController : BaseController<EntryRepo>
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Domain.Transaction.Entry> Get()
    {
        return (Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Domain.Transaction.Entry>>(Repo.GetAll()));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [SendSignalRNotification]
    public Domain.Transaction.Entry Save(Domain.Transaction.Entry newEntry)
    {
        return (Mapper.Map<Domain.Transaction.Entry>(Repo.Insert(Mapper.Map<EF.Transaction.Entry>(newEntry))));
    }
}
```

I am having two issues:
1. The `dispose` of the `BaseController` is being called before the action of the child
2. The `_repo` is always `null`, I thought `new()` would make it instantiate

I am very new to generics and I am clearly nor understanding something. Thanks!

UPDATE:

```
public abstract class BaseController<TRepo> : ApiController where TRepo : Repository<EF.DBContext>, new()
{
    private readonly TRepo _repo;

    protected TRepo Repo { get { return _repo; } }

    protected BaseController()
    {
        _repo = new TRepo();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _repo.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Per Sergey's comment I have added a constructor to the `BaseController` and `_repo` is not null anymore and the data is coming back.

However `Dispose` is still being called as the first thing in the request for some reason.

Comment: `new()` is constraint for `TRepo` type that type should have default constuctor. It won't create instance, and you need to do it manually

Comment: There is no reason to override Dispose to call _repo.Dispose() if _repo does not have unmanaged resources.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov Ok, that makes sense, see my update above.

Comment: @FacioRatio I'd still like to understand why the disposed is even being called before anything else happens.

Comment: Please read how to implement a dispose method:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Sievajet can you be more specific why my implementation would cause to be called twice? Thanks

Comment: You're implementation is called twice because you call it twice. There is no other explanation if I look at your code.

Comment: If you know how to implement the dispose pattern it shouldnt matter how many times you call dispose. Because it should support that

Comment: @Sievajet where is being called twice? Please be more specific.

Comment: You dont call dispose on the example you've posted, so you must be calling it twice from somewhere else. why dont you just put a breakpoint on the call and look at the call stack?

Comment: That's my point. It's being called by the framework itself...I don't need manually call it. Dispose is usually being called at the end of the controller cycle, which it does in my case. For some reason though it's also being called at the beginning of each request, that's part I am not understanding.

Comment: The DB.Context is created and disposed in every operation. This is designed like this. for example: SqlConnections are created and disposed on every database call. the underlying pooling mechanism handles this for you.

Comment: The 'Dispose' in question is not the 'Dispose' of the 'DBContext' but the dispose of the 'ApiController'. The issue is that it's not only being called at the end of every operation but at the very begging of an api call as well.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov Your comment solved my most pressing issue. Submit it as an answer and I'll mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comment as answer.

The issue was the `new()` is just a [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) for type that used in generic class. It will require that this type should have default constructor. If type doesn't have it, then it will produce compilation error.

So you just need to call constructor manually in the code, as code knows that type has default constructor and will be executed fine.